# Web app that "guarenteed" doesn't upload to server?

Tags: web, upload

Hi I am contemplating a browser-based app that will process confidential data (including data retrieved using local upload). I will make it so that it never invokes a backend (i.e. it will be an SPA app) but I also need a way to show this to the end-user so that the end-user can reassure himself this is the case. Of course, many users won't care, but at least security-conscious end-users will be able to reassure themselves of this. 
Yet I don't see exactly what web technology to use this to guarantee this. Of course, you could ask the end-user to check the Network tab in the Developer Console but this is not very user-friendly. The key issue is of course that web apps "per default" have access to do web requests, so how to prove the app doesn't actually use this? I am wondering if some newer web development (progressive apps, installable apps etc.) might have something to offer here? Otherwise it seems to be a sort-of flaw in the web, that you can't create an app that provably doesn't upload end-user data!

Comment: You can't, because nothing stops you from changing the behavior. Even if you were to release the entire source code of the application, you can deploy an altered version on your server. Especially parts that happen on the server side can by nature not be verified by the user.

Comment: Yes only way I immediately could see was if there was some newer concept of application permissions with the browser presenting to the user what permissions were required, of course, tied to origin, address bar, installation time, or some other mechanism etc. I haven't encountered it but created this question to get verification of the non-existence of such a mechanism. Maybe it is something browser vendors could consider for the future. I can see many complications in developing such a mechanism but it would nonetheless be useful.